# Node Update not showing to anonymous user even after clear cache

Tags: nodes, caching, updating

I have a live site , when i update any node, it is not reflected for anonymous user.Even I clear the cache.This domain has SSL certification but we use it only for few pages.But if we use https for the updated content for anonymous user, It show the updated content.
  We have used cache for bloack and anonymous user and minimum cache lifetime and cache expiration is 1 hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the value of `Expiration of cached pages` to `1 hour`

Expiration of cached pages tells the External Caches for how long they can server the old version of a page.

In your case browser is the External Cache and it assumes that it can show old content for an hour. So it doesn't even make a call to you website when you request the page.

You can see the changes after an hour or clear all your browser caches to see the new changes.

[More Explanation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/83342/4876)