# What does General Cache Wipe mean

Tags: caching, performance

The definition of CACHE_TEMPORARY used in cache_set reads as follows.

> CACHE_TEMPORARY: Indicates that the item should be removed at the next
>   general cache wipe.

I am just curious as to what `General Cache Wipe` means and what constitutes to `General Cache Wipe` other than obvious cron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any action that makes a call to either `cache_clear_all(NULL, $table);` on all core cache tables or a call to `cache_clear_all();` can be termed as `General Cache Wipe`

I could list down following based on a quick grep search for these functios.

1. Cron : Very obvious.
2. When a vote is submitted on a poll.
3. Any operation performed on `admin/content` page like

   - Node Multiple Delete. (Handled as a special case with confirmation form)
   - Any other operation like
4. When node access is rebuilt. (Like change of permissions)
5. When menu cache is cleared. (Node module clears all the caches [node_menu()])
6. Node Form Submission. [Creation or Updation]
7. Node Deletion
8. Comment Form Submission
9. Any operation performed on `admin/content/comment` page
10. Block administration. Any action performed on `admin/structure/block`
11. Create, Delete/Update any custom block.
12. Any forum form submit.
13. Any System Theme settings are changed.
14. When aggregator parses a feed.
15. Profile fields are edited/updated/deleted or their weights and categories are changed.
16. When a user account is cancelled.
17. When taxonomy term/vocabulary is added/deleted/updated.

Comment: So, if I call cache_set with CACHE_TEMPORARY, followed by cache_clear_all(), then the entry should be deleted from the database and a subsequent cache_get should not return the cached item? That doesn't seem to be the case :-(